# less command is unable to show pdf file in cygwin/mingw

Tags: pdf, cygwin, less, mingw

I use less to read pdf in linux. While either in mingw or cygwin, less is unable to show pdf in the right way. looks encoding issue. Any help? thank you!

Comment: I doubt our opening statement. `less` is useless for reading PDFs, wherever you are.

Comment: you could read pdf with no issue with less under linux. it supports lots of file types. picture, iso, pdf, etc.

Comment: wow, I didn't know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By itself, `less` is only a text pager, and will show gibberish for binary files.  However, some Linux systems are configured by default to use `lesspipe` or similar tools to present many types of binary data in some fashion.  Cygwin is not so configured by default, but it can be by installing `lesspipe`; a package is available in [Cygwin Ports](http://cygwinports.org/).